# Make partition primary from existing partition

Tags: linux, fdisk, mx-linux

This is my disk partition:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 186.3 GiB, 200049647616 bytes, 390721968 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MK2035GS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 03ADB682-C0D4-4E99-9FC9-0CF1FA085048

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  16386047  16384000  7.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda2   16386048 221186047 204800000 97.7G Linux root (x86)
/dev/sda3  221186048 390721535 169535488 80.9G Microsoft basic data

Command (m for help):
```

I have this partition :

```
/dev/sda3  221186048 390721535 169535488 80.9G Microsoft basic data
```

Now i want to make primary partition? how can i do that ?

For testing I deleted by `d` command from fdisk and this partition is deleted but when i want to add new partition by `n` command, it did not ask me about primary partition!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Disklabel type: gpt`

You have a [GPT partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) on your disk and on GPT all partitions are "primary" (there are no extended partitions on GPT) so `fdisk` won't ask about partition type, it will just create "normal" GPT partition.

The primary/extended/logical partition types are only on MSDOS partition table -- the extended partition is actually a kind of "hack" to overcome the 4 primary partition limit on MSDOS table. GPT can have up to 256 partitions so there is no need for extended (and logical) partitions.

Comment: I am trying to install hackintash so after booting usb when i want to install, it can not find my partition,so i I thought it is because of my primary partition